# I'm stuck with this integral involving $\ln x$

Tags: integration

Good morning,

I would like to ask you guys with helping me out with this integral, still can't get to the proper result...

$$\int\frac{\ln x-2}{x\sqrt{\ln x}}\,dx$$

Comment: Looks simple enough.  First things first.  What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: By "proper result" do you mean that you know what the answer should be? That makes it a lot easier to find, as then you simply have to check that it works; that its derivative is the integrand.

Comment: Well, you have an $\ln(x)$ in the numerator, and an $x$ in the denominator.  This screams $u$-substitution.

Answer (score 3):

Notice

$$ \int \frac{ \ln x - 2 }{ x \sqrt{ \ln x } } = \int \frac{ \ln x}{x \sqrt{\ln x}} dx - 2 \int \frac{dx}{x \sqrt{\ln x }} $$

Now, use $u = \ln x $ and you should be able to solve it.